# Browser keeps crashing on certain Javascript file

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, browser

First off, sorry for any bad English as it's not my primary language.

I'm having some troubles with Javascript. A certain file keeps crashing my browser (doesn't matter if it's Chrome, Firefox or IE) after a few minutes.

```
$().ready(function() {
timeAgo();
});

function timeAgo() {
    $('time.time-ago').each(function() {
    //Get datetime from the attribute
    var ago = $(this).attr('datetime');

    //Split it so we can convert it to a Date object as Firefox doesn't allow raw input
    var spl = ago.split(' ');

    var date = spl[0].split('-');

    var time = spl[1].split(':');

    //Convert to object
    ago = new Date(date[0],date[1]-1,date[2],time[0],time[1],time[2]);

    //Get current date
    var now = new Date();

    //Calculate difference in days
    var days = dayYear(now) - dayYear(ago);

    if(days < 0) days += 365;

    var out = '';

    //Get the propper string
    if(days > 0) {
        if(days == 1) {
            out = 'Gisteren';
        }else if(days < 7) {
            out = days +' dagen geleden';
        }else if(days < 14) {
            out = 'Een week geleden';
        }else{
            out = ago.toLocaleDateString('nl-nl',{day: "numeric",month: "short",year: "numeric"});
        }
    }else{
        var dif = Math.round((now - ago)/1000);
        if(dif < 10) {
            out = 'Zojuist';
        }else if(dif < 60) {
            out = 'Enkele seconden geleden';
        }else if(dif < 120) {
            out = 'Een minuut geleden';
        }else if(dif < 60 * 60) {
            out = Math.floor(dif/60)+' minuten geleden';
        }else if(dif < 60 * 60 * 2) {
            out = 'Een uur geleden';
        }else{
            out = Math.floor(dif/60/60)+' uur geleden';
        }
    }
    $(this).html(out);
});
setInterval(function(){timeAgo()},10000);
}

function dayYear(now) {
var first = new Date(now.getFullYear(),0,1);
var day = Math.round(((now - first) / 1000 / 60 / 60 /24) + 0.5);
return day;
}
```

I call it with for example the following code.

```
<time datetime="2013-05-12 19:12:15"></time>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you sure this file is the culprit? I ran your code in Chrome 26 without problems.

Comment: What do you mean "crashing" the browser? What happens to make you think something is wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason is that you keep calling `setInterval` inside every loop.

You should use `setTimeout` instead (or only call `setInterval` once)

The difference is that `setInterval` executes the given every x milliseconds.
`setTimeout`executes the given code after exactly x milliseconds (once).

Since you call `setInterval` inside the `timeAgo` method, after a while you will have a lot of timers running, all spawning new timers and the amount of timers will grow exponentially, eventually resulting in a crash.

Comment: +1 This is it. Exponential increase in number of running timers every 10 seconds.